# Bootstrap JS wont work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

This code works in FireFox and IE but not Chrome. Any ideas why? Help is appreciated. The version of Chrome I'm using is Version 53.0.2785.143 m. For some reason Chrome isn't liking the JS that's being pulled in. I'm not sure where the hang up is.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div style="width:100px;">
            <select> 
                <option>Select a language</option>
                <option data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">English</option>
                <option data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Spanish</option>
            </select>
      <!-- Modals -->
      <!-- English Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">      
              <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">English content</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
              </div>          
            </div>
          </div>
       <!-- End English Modal -->             
       <!-- Spanish Modal -->             
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">      
              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Spanish content</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>Some text in the modal2222.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
              </div>          
            </div>
          </div>
       <!-- End Spanish Modal -->  
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes are used by the `bootstrap.min.js` script to show/hide the modals when the elements with those attributes are clicked.

In this case, it seems that in `Chrome` the necessary click events are not triggered (most probably because you've used `option` elements for this).

To fix that, you can add some javascript code to open the modal when the `select`'s element values is changed. Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
      if(this.value == "English"){
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
      }else if(this.value == "Spanish"){
        $("#myModal2").modal("show");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

And here is a working example with all the code.

```js
$(function(){
        $("select").change(function(){
          if(this.value == "English"){
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
          }else if(this.value == "Spanish"){
            $("#myModal2").modal("show");
          }
        });
      });
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div style="width:100px;">
            <select> 
                <option>Select a language</option>
                <option data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">English</option>
                <option data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Spanish</option>
            </select>
      <!-- Modals -->
      <!-- English Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">      
              <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">English content</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
              </div>          
            </div>
          </div>
       <!-- End English Modal -->             
       <!-- Spanish Modal -->             
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">      
              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Spanish content</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>Some text in the modal2222.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
              </div>          
            </div>
          </div>
       <!-- End Spanish Modal -->  
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```